# Inheritance model Laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel, inheritance

I have a problem with laravel. I need to create two class like that :

```
Class Users {}
Class Companies extends Users {}
```

It's an inheritance relationship. And this is my database :

[image]

And I don't know how to create the model User and Companies in Laravel. And how to use them.
Can you help me ?

Thank you by advance !!

Comment: I'm not clear from the diagram what the relationship in the DB is - is the `id` on `companies` a foreign key to the `id` on `users`? If so, and this is an inheritance relationship (which I would read as "a company is a special type of user"), why is `siren` part of the primary key, implying that a row in `users` can be connected to more than one row in `companies`?

Comment: Yes, the id on companies is a foreign key for the id on users. And a company is special type of user :). But for one user there can be just ONE company or not.

Comment: Do you really need the inheritance here? Eloquent does not support that, it is possible to do so by overriding some of Eloquent's methods, but in your case it doesn't seem to be worth the effort. Isn't one-to-one relation between user and company enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `artisan` then things would be as simple a typing the following command in your terminal, *giving that your `pwd` is your project directory*:

```
php artisan make:model User
```

This will create a `User.php` file that is a class named User, and inherits from Model.php, eloquent's model class.

If you want to create a model and also create a table in the database with certain columns, you can use the `--migration` argument with the previous command, for instance:

```
php artisan make:model User --migration
```

After running this command, you'll have to open `database/migrations` and modify the file created as you wish to create your table.

If you do not use `artisan` -then you should be- you can just create the model manually by creating a new class in a file that extends from eloquent's model.

For instance:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model 
{

}
```

And that should be it.

For further reading, consult Laravel's documentation, it contains all your basic questions such as the one you have just asked.

For the link to the documentation about Models, clikc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Comment: Oh I think my explaination were bad. I know how to create a model and how to use it etc... 
But i don't know how to create a model with an inheritance relationship. The laravel documentation don't talk about that.

Comment: An inheritance relationship? Do you mean the OOP inheritance?